# Why does normalising a conditional probability sufficient to ensure ensure that the resulting quantity is a distribution?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, normalization

The following is said in David Barber's *Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning*:

"The relation between the conditional p(A=a | B=b) and the joint p(A=a, B=b) is just the normalisation constant since $p(A=a, B=b)$ is not a distribution in A - in other words, $\sum_a P(A=a, B=b)\not = 1$.
To make it a distribution (in A), we need to divide: $p(A=a, B=b)/ \sum_a p(A=a,B=b) $ which when summed over a does sum to 1. Indeed, this is just the definition of $p(A=a|B=b)$ "

What is the point of this excerpt?
I have two questions, please.

1. I understand that P(A=a, B=b) is of course not a probability distribution for A, but isn't this obvious?
2. If the point is that P(A=a, B=b) is not by itself a probability distribution for A, and that dividing by $\sum_a P(A=a, B=b)$ makes is a distribution as now $$\sum_a\frac{(p(A=a, B=b)}{ \sum_a p(A=a,B=b)}=1$$. My question is why is this this normalising condition sufficient to ensure that $\frac{(p(A=a, B=b)}{ \sum_a p(A=a,B=b)}$ is a distribution in A?

Answer (score 2):

1. It's obvious but still someone needs to prove it, i.e. if it doesn't sum up to $1$ for all values of $A$, it's not a distribution (PMF to be more specific) for $A$.
2. Any function which is $\geq0$ and sums up to $1$ for all the values of a RV is qualified to be a distribution for that RV. In this case, $f_{A|B=b}(a)=P(A=a|B=b)$ is nonnegative and sums up to $1$, hence a distribution for $A$.